# Why not mention angel's names?

Tags: malach-angel, shofar

The Kitzur Shulchan Aruch poskins [(129:15)](https://www.sefaria.org/Kitzur_Shulchan_Arukh.129.15?lang=bi)

> נוֹהֲגִין הָעוֹלָם לוֹמַר בֵּין הַסְּדָרִים יְהִי רָצוֹן וְכוּ',
> כְּמוֹ שֶׁנִּדְפַּס בַּמַּחֲזוֹרִים. וּצְרִיכִין לִזָּהֵר מְאֹד,
> שֶׁלֹּא לְהוֹצִיא בַּפֶּה שְׁמוֹת הַמַּלְאָכִים הַנִּזְכָּרִים שָׁם.
> וּבְהַרְבֵּה קְהִלּוֹת אֵין אוֹמְרִים כְּלָל אֶת הַיְהִי רָצוֹן, וְכֵן
> נָכוֹן יוֹתֵר. - People have the custom to recite Yehi ratzon [May it
> be the will] etc., between the three sets of shofar tones, as it is
> printed in the Machzor. You should be very careful not to articulate
> the names of the angels mentioned there. In many communities the Yehi
> ratzon is omitted entirely, and this is preferable.

What is the problem with saying the names of angels? Do others permit saying angels' names?

Comment: Or this. https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/23133/saying-names-of-angels

Comment: @Meir Thank you - this answers the first part of the question. I'm also wondering if other Poskim permit saying angels' names. (Not just a few angels, but any of them)